# Opencart | Set default Tax rate to all customer groups including ones that might be added in future | PHP

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I would like to have that GST 15% added by default to all customer groups, including the customer groups that might be added in future.Right now we are manually doing the following steps every time a new customer group is added:

> 1. Navigate System->Localisation
> 2. Under Localisation -> Taxes-> Tax rates
> 3. Click action , next GST to edit Tax rate
> 4. Select the customer groups
> 5. Save the change and clear cache ( Modificiations-> refresh)

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Customer Group, there is a table named **oc_tax_rate_to_customer_group** which updates with **customer_group_id => tax_rate_id** mapping.

You may just need to *add a single query* to this table on the creation of customer group. You will obtain the result you are looking for.